# D3 Charts Aligning the Titles and chart positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

I'm using D3 to draw a pie chart in my applicatio. I have created a pie chart with some sample data. But this chart is having alignment issues and adding a title didn't woked as expected,I added x, y attributes to place the chart but it didn't worked. I think I'm adding those to incorrect places.Can someone point out what's wrong here. Following is a sample code. My exact requirement is adding a title to the chart and getting the chart to center.
https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/r8hkpx49/7/

```
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
var r = h/2;
var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var data = [{"label":"Category A", "value":20}, 
                  {"label":"Category B", "value":50}, 
                  {"label":"Category C", "value":30}];


var vis = d3.select('#container').append("svg:svg").data([data]).attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d){return d.value;});

// declare an arc generator function
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

// select paths, use arc generator to draw
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice");
arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i){
        return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        // log the result of the arc generator to show how cool it is :)
        console.log(arc(d));
        return arc(d);
    });

// add the text
arcs.append("svg:text").attr("transform", function(d){
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = r;
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";}).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text( function(d, i) {
    return data[i].label;}
        );
```

Comment: have you any idea how you position the pie chart in the SVG? There is the answer to your question. Strange way of getting the data to the pie generator.

Comment: no I don't have an idea about that

Comment: then examine each and every sub-statement if your code and understand what it does